# Update Android on ASUS

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, asus-zenfone-5

I have an Asus T00J, "ZenFone 5" with android 4.4.2 and the manufacturer did not post updates. Can I force the update to a newer version of Android?

Comment: Check out [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-5).
 (Sorry for the last mistaken comment)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Starting point to find the answer would be our [updates tag-wiki](/tags/updates/info) – and most likely [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](/q/17152/1465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zenfone 5(T00J) is a old device now, Asus wont be pushing any updates officially after the latest Lollipop(5.0) update.
I would suggest staying with Kitkat as its better than Lollipop for Zenfone 5.
If you still want to update your zenfone 5 to latest update just follow this link: [How to update ZF5 to latest LP from KK](https://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-11408-1-1.html)